# Revoking a access token / refresh token revokes other token with different set of permissions

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am working with two sets of Google APIs and permissions one is for Google Calendar and another one is for Google Drive from the same OAuth 2.0 Client in the Google Cloud console.

From obtaining tokens to revoking I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest) article.
where it says to revoke an access token or refresh token send a post request to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke` with header `Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and param `token={token}`

When I follow the process to revoke a token for Google Drive for a user their Google Calendar token also got revoked and vice versa. I'm not sure if it's a behavior from past or it's a recent update and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revoke will revoke a users access to your application. All of it no matter what api scope you requested access for.  Its not limited by a single scope.

My question is why you have two tokens for the same user.  Why not just request drive and calendar access of the user once and have a single token granting you access to both apis?

Comment: We have bunch of third party integrations not limited to Google Calendar and Google Drive and they are independent in their use cases. So, it's a requirement letting the users choose whichever integration they want to use and find useful.

Comment: If you have a bunch of third party integrations, should be its own project. on Google cloud console.  If you do it like you are now then a revoke is going to revoke everything.

Comment: Are you telling, it needs to create a project for each integration like one for Google Calendar and one for Google Drive? If I create different OAuth 2.0 Client ID for Google Calender and Google Drive under same project in the Google Cloud won't it work?

Comment: third party integrations i assume these are different apps.  If they are the same app then you should only have one.  But you should still store a single token for each user.  If you have multiple tokens you may run into the token limit and expire one.   Just add additional scopes as you go.   Revoke should only be used if you want to totally remove the user from the system.